# TOS episode- Crew meets immortal from Earth's past

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

In this episode, Kirk and an away team go to another planet they find uninhabited except for a millennia-old man who claims to have been various figures in Earth's history, including Alexander the Great (and possibly Julius Caesar, I'm not sure).

Comment: You may find a Star Trek The Animated Series fan film "Ptolomy Wept" interesting as it is a sequel to this episode. https://youtu.be/7Q_Po_ZVO70

Comment: This episode evolved into the independent film [the man from earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Earth), I believe.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is ***[Requiem for Methuselah](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Requiem_for_Methuselah_(episode))***.

Here's Memory Alpha's brief synopsis of the episode:

> While the Enterprise searches for the rare cure to a deadly disease, the landing party is confronted by a reclusive man who is willing to kill to preserve his privacy.

And here's the actual dialogue from the relevant scene:

> MCCOY: Physically human but not human. These are earlier versions of Rayna, Jim. She's an android.
>
> FLINT: Created here by my hand. Here, the centuries of loneliness were to end.
>
> SPOCK: Your collection of Leonardo da Vinci masterpieces, Mister Flint, they appear to have been recently painted on contemporary canvas with contemporary materials. And on your piano, a waltz by Johannes Brahms, an unknown work in manuscript, written in modern ink. Yet absolutely authentic, as are your paintings.
>
> FLINT: I am Brahms.
>
> SPOCK: And da Vinci?
>
> FLINT: Yes.
>
> SPOCK: **How many other names shall we call you?**
>
> FLINT: Solomon, **Alexander**, Lazarus, Methuselah, Merlin, Abramson. A hundred other names you do not know.
>
> SPOCK: **You were born?**
>
> FLINT: **In that region of earth later called Mesopotamia, in the year 3834 BC, as the millennia are reckoned. I was Akharin, a soldier, a bully and a fool. I fell in battle, pierced to the heart and did not die.**
>
> MCCOY: **Instant tissue regeneration coupled with some perfect form of biological renewal. You learned that you were immortal and**
>
> FLINT: **And to conceal it. To live some portion of a life, to pretend to age and then move on before my nature was suspected.**
>
> SPOCK: Your wealth and your intellect are the product of centuries of acquisition. You knew the greatest minds in history.
>
> FLINT: Galileo, Socrates, Moses. I have married a hundred times, Captain. Selected, loved, cherished. Caressed a smoothness, inhaled a brief fragrance. Then age, death, the taste of dust. Do you understand?
>
> SPOCK: You wanted a perfect, ultimate woman, as brilliant, as immortal as yourself. Your mate for all time.
>
> FLINT: Designed by my heart. I could not love her more.
>
> <sub>*Star Trek: The Original Series* S03E21 "Requiem for Methuselah"</sub>

Comment: Worth noting that Captain Janeway on *Voyager* recalls that James T. Kirk claimed to have met Leonardo Da Vinci, but says the evidence was not conclusive. A holodecck simulation of him was a recurring character, and did not have the memories of Methuselah.

Comment: @Davislor, the holodeck recreation would have been based on information _known_ about Da Vinci, and would not include any revelations from Kirk's encounter with Flint, whose existence Kirk promised not to reveal.

Comment: @RobJarvis Except that Janeway knew all about it.

Comment: Two or three of the ST:TNG/DS9/VOY novels had a sequel of a type to "Requiem for Methuselah".  Dr. Soong in an android body discovers that Flint has stolen his Juliana Soong (android), but cannot go after her.